# How to show the front end in a different language? I am using the twentytwentythree theme

Tags: localization

1. I don't see the language files in the theme folder. Shouldn't they be available by default?
2. Once I get the language files, where should I copy them and what should be the naming convention?
3. Will all translatable texts show up automatically?

Comment: They're available from http://api.wordpress.org/translations/themes/1.0/?slug=twentytwentythree&version=1.1 . I think WordPress installs them itself if you select the language in the dashboard (Settings, General), but I don't know all the details.

Comment: You shouldn’t need to do anything. If translations are available you should just need to switch your site language and the theme should be translated. You _may_ need to update translations in _Dashboard > Updates_, bu that’s all.

Comment: @rup WordPress does download the translations but only the core translations that go in the wp-content/languages folder. It does *not* however download the theme's translations which go in the wp-content/languages/themes folder. Do you know how that happens?

Comment: No, sorry, I had assumed that happened when you changed languages or changed theme. Worst case you can grab them from that API endpoint yourself I suppose.

Comment: Interestingly, the theme files get downloaded after a delay of around 30-40 minutes.